# Connecting database using PHP with some other way in android

Tags: php, android

Okay so I have already achieved the above task, but I am not satisfied with it. It looks very complex.

I need some other way around to solve this, as I have very less experience in android developing and cant find any other way.

Here's how I've done it. I will show You simple login system which accesses the database.

**Here is the login activity.**

```
package com.example.andorid.ersnexus.userlogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
mport android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.R;
import
com.example.andorid.ersnexus.userprofile.homeactivity.
UserProfileHomeActivity;
import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.usersignup.UserSignUpActivity;
import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.util.SharedPreferencesData;
import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.webservices.BackgroundDbConnector;


//This is the main activity of the app.
//It is the user login screen where users logs in or sign up's.

public class UserLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mUserName;
private EditText mUserPassword;
private Button mLoginButton;
private Button mSignUpButton;
//private UserBaseHelper mHelper;
private String userName;
private String pass;
//private String password;
//private String mErno;
public static Activity mActivity;
public static Boolean mActive;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);

    mActivity = this;

    Boolean status = SharedPreferencesData.getStoredLoginStatus(UserLoginActivity.this);
    if(status){
        Intent i = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, UserProfileHomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    //mHelper = new UserBaseHelper(this);


    //user UserName editText in activity_user_login
    mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_user_name);


    //PASSWORD editText
    mUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_user_pass);


    //SignUp button
    mSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, UserSignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    //Login Button
    mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if(isNetworkAvailableAndConnected()) {
                /*try {
                    if(!InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.3").isReachable(5000)){
                        throw new Exception("Host does not exist::");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,
                            "Server Is Down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
                String type = "login";
                userName = mUserName.getText().toString();
                pass = mUserPassword.getText().toString();
                //password = mHelper.fetchUserPass(userName);
               //mErno = mHelper.fetchErNo(userName);
                //String fullName = mHelper.fetchFullName(userName);

                ***BackgroundDbConnector backgroundDbConnector = new
                        BackgroundDbConnector(UserLoginActivity.this);
                backgroundDbConnector.execute(type, userName, pass);***

                SharedPreferencesData.setStoredUsername(UserLoginActivity.this, userName);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,
                        "No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mActive = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mActive = false;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailableAndConnected () {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    boolean isNetworkAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;

    return isNetworkAvailable &&
            cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}

}
```

**The Post request is send via a backgroundTask here**

```
BackgroundDbConnector backgroundDbConnector = new
                        BackgroundDbConnector(UserLoginActivity.this);

backgroundDbConnector.execute(type, userName, pass);
```

**Then in the backGround AsyncTask following things happens:**

```
 try {
                //Fetch the username and password from the background method call.
                String username = params[1];
                String password = params[2];

                mHttpURLConnection = URLManager.
                        getConnection(URLManager.LOGIN_URL);

                //Creating the outputStream
                OutputStream outputStream = mHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                //Writing in the outputStream.
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new
                        OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                //This is for connecting the variables in the app and in the php file.
                String postData = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" +//$_POST["username"]
                        URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +//$_POST["password"]
                        URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                //Feeding the data.
                bufferedWriter.write(postData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                //Creating an inputStream to fetch the results.
                InputStream inputStream = mHttpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

                //Getting the results
                String result = "";
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                mHttpURLConnection.disconnect();
                //Returning the results
                return result;
}
```

**And finally the php file is as follows:**

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM student_data WHERE username='$user_name' AND 
password='$user_pass';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row_cnt > 0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$erno = $row["enrollmentnumber"];
echo $erno;
} 
else{
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

So most database connectivity is done this way and I need some other way around to do this

I am having a gut feeling and as you can see that the backGround Task needs to be handled in some other way,but I am not getting one...

So those who have good experience in Android, please guide me through the right path.

Thanks in advance to those dev's who takes their time and reads my code.

And here is my link to the project. Please have a look and test if u want, to I would love the opinions regarding my code.

https://github.com/shrungBhatt/ErNexus

Comment: You are putting user input directly into your database query - ***very bad, very dangerous***

Comment: If i am logging in then I need to fetch the username directly from the editText.Or are u saying that I should encrypt it first and then send it than decrypt then put it in the query ?

Comment: He is talking about the way you trust user input `$user_name = $_POST["username"];`. And then prepared SQL without security checks.

Comment: This `"SELECT * FROM student_data WHERE username='$user_name' AND password='$user_pass'"` is your problem: If someone enters `; \! rm -rf /*.*` as their `username` you can say goodbye to your operating system and  all of your files.   BTW, you don't need the `;` semicolon at the end of the query string.

Comment: Yes I got your point. So what should I do to give that protection? As far I thought I could just frame the query in the if and compare the username with erroneous commands ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found an alternative, and its very cute to implement.

```
try {
            //Fetch the username and password from the background method call.
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            mHttpURLConnection = URLManager.
                    getConnection(URLManager.LOGIN_URL);

            //Creating the outputStream
            OutputStream outputStream = mHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            //Writing in the outputStream.
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new
                    OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            //This is for connecting the variables in the app and in the php file.
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" +//$_POST["username"]
                    URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +//$_POST["password"]
                    URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            //Feeding the data.
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Creating an inputStream to fetch the results.
            InputStream inputStream = mHttpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            //Getting the results
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            mHttpURLConnection.disconnect();
            //Returning the results
            return result;
}
```

**All the Above code was replaced by the following using Volley.**
**And Here is the new code**

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLManager.
                        LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response != null &&
                                !response.equals("Wrong Username or Password")) {
                            SharedPreferencesData.setStoredLoginStatus(mContext, true);
                            SharedPreferencesData.setStoredErno(mContext, response);
                            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,
                                    UserProfileHomeActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong Username or Password!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this, error.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put(KEY_USERNAME, userName);
                        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pass);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                SharedPreferencesData.setStoredUsername(UserLoginActivity.this, userName);

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserLoginActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```